# Class-based Vue component does not work with v-model and vuex

Tags: typescript, vue-component, vuex, bootstrap-vue, vue-property-decorator

I want to achieve the following: I have a form input and need to bind it to the value of the corresponding stored state in vuex.

- Whenever the value in the field changes via user interaction, the store gets overwritten with the updated value.
- Whenever the value is updated in the vuex store, the field displays the updated value

The following code snippet should describe it pretty well:

```
<template>
    <b-form-input
      :id="inputField.id"
      :placeholder="inputField.placeholder"
      :disabled="inputField.disabled"
      v-model="input"
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import ...

    @Component
    export default class InputWrapper extends Vue {
        @Prop() element!: Input

        inputField: Input = new Input(this.element)

        get input (): string {
            return this.$store.getters.getInputById(this.inputField.id).value
        }

        set input (value: string) {
            this.inputField.value = value
            this.$store.commit('setInput', this.inputField)
        }
    }

</script>
```

The above example will store the updated value for every change the user makes in the GUI, however, if I change the value of the corresponding stored instance in vuex, the field will still display the old value instead of the updated one.

How can I achieve the mentioned functionality described at the listing at the top? Is this somehow possible with class-based components?

Comment: You are using `:id="inputField.name"` in your template but you used `getInputById(this.inputField.id).value` in the script. Is'nt this the cause of your problem?

Comment: Good point, but unfortunately it is not. There is both name and id in Input. I could easily interchange it (already did in edit) and it would result in the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized your store value ?
Having an uninitialized store value usually leads to non reactive properties, even within a vuex store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually solved this a long time ago and forgot about this post. I have restructured the whole concept so it is hard to say if that was part of the solution.